# bind switch and form input in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm looking for the VueJS best practice for synchronizing between the input element and the switch element in the following piece of code:

```
<div class="filter panel">
  <div class="field_title">Device</div>
  <el-switch v-model="switches.device_switch" name="device"></el-switch>
  <b-form-input v-model="device" placeholder="Device"></b-form-input>
</div>
```

If the input field contains any text I would like to set the `v-model="switches.device_switch"` to `true`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a watcher for the `device` property bound to the input. In the watcher, you can set the value of `switches.device_switch` based on the length of the `device` string:

```
watch: {
  device: function(value) {
    this.switches.device_switch = value.length !== 0;
  }
}
```